# Fork NodeJS clusters as working load changes

Tags: node.js

I am trying to **fork worker clusters to a maximun of 10, and only if the working load increases**. Can it be done?

I have tried with [strong-cluster-control's *setSize*](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/strong-cluster-control/#control-setsizen), but I can't find an easy way of forking automatically (if many requests are being done then fork, for example), or closing/"suiciding" forks (maybe with a timeOut if nothing is being done, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938076))

[This is my repo's main file at GitHub](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/webcase/blob/master/app.js)

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you already have some idea as to how you would like to spread your load so I will not include details about that and instead focus on the interprocess communication required for this.

#### Notifying the master

To send arbitrary data to the master, you can use [process.send()](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle) from a worker. The way I would go about this is probably something along these steps:

1. The application is started
2. Minimum amount of workers are spawned
3. Each worker will send the master a `request` message every time it receives a new request, via `process.send()`
4. The master keeps track of all the `request` events from all workers
5. If the amount of `request` events increases above a predefined threshold (i.e. > 100 requests/s) it spawns a new worker
6. If the amount of `request` events decreases below a predefined threshold it asks one of the workers to stop processing new requests and close itself gracefully (note that it should not simply kill the process to avoid interrupting ongoing requests)

**Main point is: Do not focus on time - focus on rate**. In an application that is supposed to handle tens to thousands of requests per second, your `setTimout()` (the task of which might be to kill the worker if it has been idle for too long) will never fire because [Node.js evenly distributes your load](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy) across your workers - you could start with one worker, but once you reach your maximum you will never drop to one worker again under continuous load even if there is only one request per second.

It should be noted that it is counterproductive to spawn more workers than the amount of CPU cores you have at your disposal. It might, however, be beneficial to start with a single worker and incrementally increase the amount to all cores as load increases.

Comment: Great! [Here is the git repo](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/webcase/blob/v1.0/app.js) of how I followed your instructions. There's still a warning when spawning more than 10 workers (after having closed 10 previously), saying that there are too many EventListeners (for sending the master a `request` message). I'd like to disable those previous listeners so the new ones count as new, and no warning is shown, but I don't know how. Anyway, thanks!!!!!

Comment: Interesting - I would expect that the cluster module would unregister its listeners from the process. Perhaps this is a bug...

Comment: So I thought, Robert. Maybe just [killing the forks](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/webcase/blob/master/app.js#L106) is not enough... And I couldn't set more listeners (or [it was not the right place](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/webcase/blob/master/app.js#L93))